# Are there any open source C libraries with common data structures?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm looking for a C library with common reusable data structures like linked lists, hash tables etc. Something like the source distributed with [Mastering Algorithms with C (Paperback) by Kyle Loudon](http://www.amazon.ca/Mastering-Algorithms-C-Kyle-Loudon/dp/1565924533/ref=sr_1_19?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1237597047&sr=1-19).

Comment: Other sites are better suited to these kinds of questions https://www.slant.co/improve/topics/19233

Answer (score 63):

BSD [queue.h](http://openbsd.su/src/sys/sys/queue.h) has:

- SLIST = singly linked list
- LIST = doubly linked list
- SIMPLEQ = singly linked queue
- TAILQ = doubly linked queue

BSD [tree.h](http://openbsd.su/src/sys/sys/tree.h) has:

- RB - red-black tree
- SPLAY - splay tree

See the [queue(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=queue) and [tree(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tree) man pages for details.  I really like them because they are pure C macros without dependencies (not even libc).  Plus with the BSD license you don't have to worry about any company restrictions w/ GPL.

Answer (score 39):

Gnome provides an excellent library for this, called [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/), with many useful data structures and other utilities as well.

Answer (score 32):

[gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/), the gnu portability library.

It's distributed as source code.
This list is from its [module list](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/MODULES.html), which includes a TON of other things. One interesting one is "c-stack: Stack overflow handling, causing program exit."

- list
- array-list
- carray-list
- linked-list
- avltree-list
- rbtree-list
- linkedhash-list
- avltreehash-list
- rbtreehash-list
- sublist ( Sequential list data type backed by another list. )
- oset (Abstract ordered set.)
- array-oset
- avltree-oset
- rbtree-oset

Comment: Keep in mind that this option is GPL-licensed, and therefore can only be used legally in GPL-licensed software.

Answer (score 21):

[SGLIB](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent generic data-structures library. The library currently provides generic implementations for: 
sorting arrays 
linked lists 
sorted linked lists 
double linked lists 
red-black trees 
hashed containers

It's very fast, faster than glib.  It's inspired by the Standard Template Library. [Download Here](http://freshmeat.net/projects/sglib)

Another solution is [Attractive Chaos software](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/programs/). 
C macro library: 
kbtree.h: efficient B-tree library in C.
khash.h: fast and light-weighted hash table library in C.
kvec.h: simple vector container in C.

Sglib and Attractive Chaos software are C macros library. Using void* to implement generic containers in C may be inefficient. C macros mimics C++ template and are as efficient  as C++ template

Comment: Nice pointers - I'd never heard of SGLIB before.

Comment: The "download" link for the SGLIB project is broken. Seems like going defunct... :/

Comment: @luis.espinal It can still be downloaded from http://freecode.com/projects/sglib

Comment: Seems both these libs have gone AWOL.

Comment: klib has some activity, but i cant find any other hashtable fast as this, someone has some other option?
https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/commits/master

Answer (score 5):

The GDSL Library might be a good thing to consider:

http://home.gna.org/gdsl/

Answer (score 3):

The Apache Portable Runtime.

Comment: Found here: https://apr.apache.org/

Answer (score -1):

[CLIB](http://code.google.com/p/cstl/)

Comment: This points to a page saying that the library has moved off to http://code.google.com/p/clibutils/.

Comment: And now it appears to be: https://github.com/davinash/cstl It hasn't been updated since 2012 though.

Answer (score -4):

AT&T's [software tools](http://www.research.att.com/software_tools).